# How to get the value from the list that appears only once?

Tags: regex, perl

I saw this question in the internet. Get the only number that is present only once in the list while other numbers are present twice in the list. The data is large and contains about a million numbers unsorted and may contain negative numbers too of random order out of which all numbers appear twice except one number that appears only once.

```
my @array = (1,1,2,3,3,4,4)
```

output :

```
2
```

Only two is not repeated in the list. I tried my solutions.

```
my $unique;
$unique ^= $_ for(@array);
say $unique;
```

It doesn't work on negative numbers but fast.

I tried a hash where key is the number and value is the number of times its present in the list. Reverse the hash and then print the value with 1 as key as all other numbers have 2 as key as they appear twice. The hash solution is slow with a large input of one million numbers but works for negative numbers.

I tried a regex way of combining the entire list with tab and then used

```
my $combined = join " ", @array;
$combined !~ (\d+).*$1;
say $1;
```

but I get only the last number of the list

Is there a fast way to do it? Any idea of using a regex?

Edit : Repharsed the title for better answers

Comment: Thanks Lee Duhem for the edit.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list is monotonically increasing?

Comment: @SzG No, the list is unsorted and can contain both negative and positive numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems pretty fast:

```
use v5.10; use strict; use warnings;

sub there_can_be_only_one {
    my @counts;
    $counts[ $_>=0 ? 2*$_ : (-2*$_)-1 ]++ for @{$_[0]};
    $counts[ $_>=0 ? 2*$_ : (-2*$_)-1 ]==1 and return $_ for @{$_[0]};
    return;
}

my @array = (1,1,-4,-4,2,3,-1,3,4,-1,4);
say there_can_be_only_one(\@array);
```

It's basically a variation of the hash technique, but using an array instead of a hash. Because we need to deal with negative numbers, we can't use them unmodified in the `@counts` array. Negative indexes do work in Perl of course, but they'd overwrite our data for positive indexes. Fail.

So we use something similar to two's complement. We store positive numbers in the array as `2*$_` and negative numbers as `(-2*$_)-1`. That is:

```
Integer:   ... -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3 ...
Stored as: ...  5   3   1   0   2   4   6 ...
```

Because this solution doesn't rely on sorting the list, and simply does two passes over it (well, on average, one and a half passes), it performs at *O(n)* in contrast to Schwern's *O(n log n)* solution. Thus for larger lists (a few million integers) should be significantly faster. Here's a quick comparison on my (fairly low-powered) netbook:

```
use v5.10; use strict; use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(timethese);
use Time::Limit '60';

sub tobyink {
    my @counts;
    $counts[ $_>=0 ? 2*$_ : (-2*$_)-1 ]++ for @{$_[0]};
    $counts[ $_>=0 ? 2*$_ : (-2*$_)-1 ]==1 and return $_ for @{$_[0]};
    return;
}

sub schwern {
    my @nums = sort @{$_[0]};
    return $nums[0] if $nums[0] != $nums[1];
    for (1..$#nums-1) {
         my($prev, $this, $next) = @nums[$_-1, $_, $_+1];
         return $this if $prev != $this && $next != $this;
    }
    return $nums[-1] if $nums[-1] != $nums[-2];
}

my @input = (
    1..2_000_000,  # 1_000_001 only appears once
    1..1_000_000, 1_000_002..2_000_000,
);

timethese(1, {
    tobyink  => sub { tobyink(\@input) },
    schwern  => sub { schwern(\@input) },
});

__END__
Benchmark: timing 1 iterations of schwern, tobyink...
schwern: 11 wallclock secs ( 8.72 usr +  0.92 sys =  9.64 CPU) @  0.10/s (n=1)
         (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
tobyink:  5 wallclock secs ( 5.01 usr +  0.08 sys =  5.09 CPU) @  0.20/s (n=1)
         (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
```

**UPDATE:** in my initial answer I missed the detail that no number will appear more than twice. I'd assumed that it was possible for some numbers to appear three or more times. Using this additional detail, we can go even faster:

```
sub there_can_be_only_one {
    my $tmp;
    $tmp ^= $_>=0 ? 2*$_ : (-2*$_)-1 for @{$_[0]};
    $tmp%2 ? ($tmp+1)/-2 : $tmp/2;
}

say there_can_be_only_one(\@array);
```

This runs about 30% faster than my initial answer.

Comment: Using an array has serious memory implications.  Add `1_000_000_000, 1_000_000_000` to the input and it's spending 30 seconds just allocating memory.  A DOS attack waiting to happen.  In addition, because the algorithms are allowed to bail out as soon as they find the one, you're actually testing the order in which they check the numbers.  If `schwern` sorts numerically it runs as fast as `tobyink`.  `there_can_be_only_one` remains the fastest and least memory.

Comment: Indeedy. I was assuming that the numbers would be roughly contiguous. If they're sparse, then a hash makes much better memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to deal with this is to throw it all into a hash.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = (2..500_000, 500_002..1_000_000, 0..1_000_001);

my %count;
for (@nums) {
    $count{$_}++
}

for (keys %count) {
    say $_ if $count{$_} == 1;
}
```

But yes, it's quite slow.

Then I thought maybe I could avoid having to loop through the hash to find the singles...

```
my @nums = (2..500_000, 500_002..1_000_000, 0..1_000_001);
my %uniqs;
my %dups;
for (@nums) {
    if( $uniqs{$_} ) {
        delete $uniqs{$_};
        $dups{$_} = 1;
    }
    elsif( !$dups{$_} ) {
        $uniqs{$_} = 1;
    }
}

print join ", ", keys %uniqs;
```

But that was even slower.

This is the fastest thing I've come up with, takes about half the time as the above.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @nums = (2..500_000, 500_002..1_000_000, 0..1_000_001);
@nums = sort @nums;
say $nums[0] if $nums[0] != $nums[1];
for (1..$#nums-1) {
    my($prev, $this, $next) = @nums[$_-1, $_, $_+1];
    say $this if $prev != $this && $next != $this;
}
say $nums[-1] if $nums[-1] != $nums[-2];
```

By sorting the list, you can iterate through it and check if a given entry's neighbors are duplicates.  Have to be careful about the first and last elements.  I put their checks outside the loop to avoid having to run a special case for every iteration.

Because `sort` is O(nlogn), as the list of numbers gets larger this solution will eventually be slower than the hash-based one, but you'll probably run out of memory before that happens.

Finally, if this list is large, you should consider storing it on disk in a database.  Then you can avoid using up memory and let the database do the work efficiently.

Comment: I think you have to use spaceship operator for sort. Thanks for the reply. Using XOR it is fast.

Comment: @Wordzilla You're right that the default sort is ASCIIbetical, and I hadn't considered that.  Thinking about it now, the sorting criterion does not matter.  All that matters for our purposes is the same entries will be sorted the same.  The default sort is fastest.

Comment: Because you're being thorough, the final search takes 2 N comparisons.  If we took advantage of the full info, a binary search is possible bringing this to O(Log N) comparisons.  It'd be kind of fun to code a sort routine that also took advantage of this info as well.  A quicksort could divide the list in two on a pivot, and completely disregard the "half" with even number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

*It doesn't work on negative numbers but fast.*

Actually, if you want xor to work on negative numbers, you just need to stringify them:

```
my @array = (-10..-7,-5..10,-10..10);

my $unique;
$unique ^= "$_" for @array;
say $unique;
```

Outputs

```
-6
```

And doing some quick benchmarks:

```
Benchmark: timing 100 iterations of schwern, there_can_be_only_one, tobyink, xor_string...
   schwern: 323 wallclock secs (312.42 usr +  7.08 sys = 319.51 CPU) @  0.31/s (n=100)
there_can_be_only_one: 114 wallclock secs (113.49 usr +  0.02 sys = 113.51 CPU) @  0.88/s (n=100)
   tobyink: 177 wallclock secs (176.76 usr +  0.14 sys = 176.90 CPU) @  0.57/s (n=100)
xor_string: 98 wallclock secs (97.05 usr +  0.00 sys = 97.05 CPU) @  1.03/s (n=100)
```

Shows that xor-ing the string goes 15% faster than xor-ing the mathematical translation to the positive numbers.

## Corollary - What about with a sorted list?

Schwern's solution brings up an interesting corollary.  He sorted the list and then did a search for all of the unique elements.

If we use the additional information that there is only 1 singleton in a crowd of doubletons, we can quickly simplify that the search by doing a pairwise comparison which reduces our comparisons a factor of 4.

However, we can do even better by doing a binary search.  If we separate the list on a barrier between a known matched pair, then whichever of the two remaining lists is odd contains our singleton.  I did some benchmarking of this solution, and it's orders of magnitude faster than anything else (of course):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(timethese);

sub binary_search {
    my $nums = $_[0];
    
    my $min = 0;
    my $max = $#$nums;
    while ($min < $max) {
        my $half = ($max - $min) / 2; # should  always be an integer
        my ($prev, $this, $next) = ($min+$half-1) .. ($min+$half+1);

        if ($nums->[$prev] == $nums->[$this]) {
            if ($half % 2) {         # 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 ( half = 3 )
                $min = $next;
            } else {                 # 0 1 1 2 2 ( half = 2 )
                $max = $prev - 1;
            }
        } elsif ($nums->[$this] == $nums->[$next]) { 
            if ($half % 2) {         # 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 ( half = 3 )
                $max = $prev;
            } else {                 # 0 0 1 1 2 ( half = 2 )
                $min = $next + 1;          
            }
        } else {
            $max = $min = $this;
        }
    }

    return $nums->[$min];
}

sub xor_string {
    my $tmp;
    $tmp ^= "$_" for @{$_[0]};
}

sub brute {
    my $nums = $_[0];

    return $nums->[0] if $nums->[0] != $nums->[1];
    for (1..$#$nums-1) {
        my($prev, $this, $next) = @$nums[$_-1, $_, $_+1];
        return $this if $prev != $this && $next != $this;
    }
    return $nums->[-1] if $nums->[-1] != $nums->[-2];
}

sub pairwise_search {
    my $nums = $_[0];
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$nums; $i += 2) {
        if ($nums->[$i] != $nums->[$i+1]) {
            return $nums->[$i];
        }
    }
}

# Note: this test data is very specific and is intended to take near the maximum
# number of steps for a binary search while shortcutting halfway for brute force
# and pairwise
my @input = sort {$a <=> $b} (0..500_003, 500_005..1_000_000, 0..1_000_000);
#my @input = sort {$a <=> $b} (0..499_996, 499_998..1_000_000, 0..1_000_000);

timethese(1000, {
    brute  => sub { brute(\@input) },
    pairwise  => sub { pairwise_search(\@input) },
    xor_string => sub { xor_string(\@input) },
    binary => sub { binary_search(\@input) },
});
```

Results:

```
Benchmark: timing 1000 iterations of binary, brute, pairwise, xor_string...
    binary:  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.02 CPU) @ 62500.00/s (n=1000)
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
     brute: 472 wallclock secs (469.92 usr +  0.05 sys = 469.97 CPU) @  2.13/s (n=1000)
  pairwise: 216 wallclock secs (214.74 usr +  0.00 sys = 214.74 CPU) @  4.66/s (n=1000)
xor_string: 223 wallclock secs (221.74 usr +  0.06 sys = 221.80 CPU) @  4.51/s (n=1000)
```

Comment: Thanks! I dint think of stringifying the number and XORing it.